# Number sequences hiding in TravelItineraryReadRQ

Tags: sabre

I'm using TravelItineraryReadRQ to get information about Price Quotes in pnr. In some cases service response hides number sequences with ("XXXX") even if it was not credit card information. For example:
PQ creation commatnd: WPASU‡EDUFS123456‡FINVOICE*QUW12345‡RQ«
and here is what I get in response:

```
<tir39:PricedItinerary DisplayOnly="false" InputMessage="WPASU¥EDUFS1XXXX6¥FINVOICE*QUW1XXX5¥RQ" RPH="1" StatusCode="A" StoredDateTime="2018-12-21T09:13" TaxExempt="false" ValidatingCarrier="SU">
                    <tir39:AirItineraryPricingInfo>
                        <tir39:ItinTotalFare>
                            <tir39:BaseFare Amount="1980" CurrencyCode="RUB"/>
                            <tir39:Taxes>
                                <tir39:Tax Amount="2541" TaxCode="XT"/>
                                <tir39:TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">2265YQ</tir39:TaxBreakdownCode>
                                <tir39:TaxBreakdownCode TaxPaid="false">276RI</tir39:TaxBreakdownCode>
                            </tir39:Taxes>
                            <tir39:TotalFare Amount="4521" CurrencyCode="RUB"/>
                            <tir39:Totals>
                                <tir39:BaseFare Amount="1980"/>
                                <tir39:Taxes>
                                    <tir39:Tax Amount="2541"/>
                                </tir39:Taxes>
                                <tir39:TotalFare Amount="4521"/>
                            </tir39:Totals>
                        </tir39:ItinTotalFare>
                        <tir39:PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="01"/>
                        <tir39:PTC_FareBreakdown>
                            <tir39:Endorsements>
                                <tir39:Endorsement type="PRICING_PARAMETER">
                                    <tir39:Text>WPASU$EDUFS1XXXX6$FINVOICE*QUW1XXX5$RQ</tir39:Text>
                                </tir39:Endorsement>
```

Is there any way to get those numbers?

Comment: Have you tried adding CCVIEW to the EPR and sending the request with the option to unhide the payment info?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sabre has logic on their end due to GDPR requirements that masks credit card info from being viewed unless you have the CC in the correct form of payment field AND your EPR has the "CCVIEW" attribute assigned.

Essentially, Sabre doesn't want CC data stored anywhere but the secured Form of Payment field and they control who can and cannot see that data by using the EPR Keywords (the login info you get from Sabre).

So, for your example, my guess is that Sabre's regex or whatever they use to identify credit card data sees your strings in those fields, assumes they are CC numbers, and masks them. You may want to open a ticket with Sabre to address this, or as Andy K suggested above, try adding CCVIEW to that EPR (although I think that probably won't work).